# Cannot access variables from Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, global-variables

I am new to android.I have spent too much time solving this issue with no success.

So i have service `Serv.java`.

```
public class Serv extends Service {
private String a = "aa";
private String b = "bb";
private String c = "100";

//called by some class.
public void setcc(String s) {
c=s;//c="cc"
}

//Using alarm manager to start the service.
//I call function callMe from OnStart.

void callMe(Context context){ 
//which calls an async task
new VAsyncTask().execute("");
}

private class VerifyCPIAsyncTask  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
    //I am able to access a and b.(aa and bb)
    //but not c.(It still shows 100 and not cc)
    }
    ........
   }
```

But when i run the same service again it shows correct value for c(cc).There is problem when i am accessing for the first time.

EDIT- The flow works fine if i make private String c to private static String c.
And i have put logs in my onCreate and onStartCommand.They do not print the latest value of variable c.so there is no use passing (latest)variable c to preexecute or even create a constructor in the aysnctask(cause i still get the old value of variable c).

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you set the parameters which ever you want using the `Preexecute` method in the `Asynctask` ?

Comment: Without knowing the process a bit more and understanding how you are utilizing everything all I can assume is this is a race condition or something.

Comment: Hi can u please have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689841/cannot-access-values-first-time)

Answer (score 0):

its difficult to tell without knowing from where/what and how your flow is?

you can override the constructor and pass the values as  async task parameter .

*

```
private class VerifyCPIAsyncTask  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
 {
    int cc
    VerifyCPIAsyncTask (int a) {
       cc= a;
     }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
}*
```

and call your async task  as new VAsyncTask(cc).execute("");

it is safer approach.

Comment: Hi can u please have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689841/cannot-access-values-first-time)